# Inconsistent behaviour with LIS3MDL magnetic sensor

Tags: sensor, c, freertos

I'm working on implementing a driver for the LIS3MDL magnetic sensor using FreeRTOS under the hood with some of our in-house functionality as well.

Link to the device [documentation](https://www.st.com/en/mems-and-sensors/lis3mdl.html#documentation) if useful (used datasheet/product specification and application note).

I have now run into some inconsistent behaviour with the driver. Sometimes reading the magnetic fields (function attached below) simply times out when "continuing" in debug mode, but doesn't when "stepping through". When looking at the SPI lines with an analyser during the transaction, all seems to be normal, except when requesting the content of the status register - it is simply 0 which means that no data is available (but it should).

Also when setting the device to idle mode and then back to continuous reading mode (registers are returning correct mode value) the device sometimes is able to read once and sometimes it times out on the first try. The who am I and temperature readings work just fine.

The magnetic field read function:

```c
drv_error_t lis3mdl_mag(uint8_t sensor_index, lis3mdl_data_t *data) {
  DRV_ASSERT(sensor_index > 0);
  DRV_ASSERT(sensor_index <= LIS3MDL_NR_OF_MAG);
  DRV_ASSERT(data);

  uint8_t sen_idx = sensor_index - 1;

  DRV_ASSERT(g_spi_index[sen_idx]);

  if (xSemaphoreTakeRecursive(g_mutex[sen_idx], LIS3MDL_TIMEOUT_MS) == pdFALSE)
    return drv_dev_error(DRV_TIMEOUT_ERROR);

  uint8_t available = 0;
  uint8_t reg_values[6];
  int16_t values[3];

  drv_error_t error;

  // Sensor specific data output period
  uint16_t output_period = g_output_periods[sen_idx]; // This is derived from the output data rate

  uint32_t timeout = 5 * output_period;
  drv_timeout_handle_t timeout_handle = drv_timeout_create(timeout);

  while (drv_timeout(&timeout_handle)) {
    if ((error = get_register(sensor_index, LIS3MDL->STATUS_REG, &available, 1, false)).code)
      break;

    // If status_reg[3] == 1 (ZYXDA bit), some data has been overwritten
    if ((available >> 3) & 1) {
      // Reading output data
      if ((error = get_register(sensor_index, LIS3MDL->OUT_X_L, reg_values, 6, true)).code)
        break;

      // x-axis
      values[0] = (reg_values[1] << 8) | reg_values[0];
      // y-axis
      values[1] = (reg_values[3] << 8) | reg_values[2];
      // z-axis
      values[2] = (reg_values[5] << 8) | reg_values[4];

      // Convert according to the range
      data->x = get_converted_value(sensor_index, values[0]);
      data->y = get_converted_value(sensor_index, values[1]);
      data->z = get_converted_value(sensor_index, values[2]);

      break;
    }

    vTaskDelay(output_period / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }

  if (!drv_timeout(&timeout_handle))
    error = drv_dev_error(DRV_TIMEOUT_ERROR);

  xSemaphoreGiveRecursive(g_mutex[sen_idx]);

  return error;
}
```

and the `get_converted_value` function:

```c
static float get_converted_value(uint8_t sensor_index, int16_t value) {
  float sensitivity = (float)g_range_cfgs[sensor_index - 1].sensitivity; // This is taken from the application note
  return ((float)value) / sensitivity;
}
```

The `get_register` function simply uses SPI to get the content of a specified register. It can also be used to get multiple registers at once like when reading the OUT_X_L register.

So I was wondering if anyone has had these kinds of issues before with the device as well? Is it more likely to be a software bug rather than a hardware one? Just bad code practices? Could I have misconfigured the device or used some wrong constants? Any specific things (timings, values, etc) I could try with the device?

I can share more code if needed.

EDIT:

After a few hours of extensive debugging we noticed that when reading the status register twice back to back, the value the second time tells that z-axis data is not available. This is quite a weird behaviour since no reading of other registers was done at that time.

So we resorted to just using the X and Y data available bits of the status register which seems to work quite fine for our implementation.
Updated reading loop if anyone's interested:

```c
...

if ((error = get_register(sensor_index, LIS3MDL->STATUS_REG, &available, 1, false)).code)
  break;

if (available & 0b11) {
  if ((error = get_register(sensor_index, LIS3MDL->OUT_X_L, reg_values, 6, true)).code)
    break;

...
```

Still, if anyone knows a different workaround or fix, all help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you probe clock + data  in each mode?

Comment: Yes, I used an 8-channel digital logic analyser and PulseView to decode the transactions. Everything seemed fine - setting/getting the mode, getting specific registers, etc. The one thing that was not OK was the status register (which was 0). I don't currently have access to the device physically (working from home), but I can probe/debug some things more thoroughly tomorrow.

Comment: It could very well be errata. Do a manual read without the driver and see what happens to see if it is hardware or not.

Comment: Note that debuggers displaying memory maps etc might decide to read SPI status registers. Now if those registers are cleared with a read access, as is common, the debugger might actually destroy status flags. Though that issue typically manifests itself the other way around: doesn't work when single-stepping, works when free running.

Comment: Though overall this is smelly code, with assignment inside condition, shifts of signed integers etc. I wouldn't assume that "get_register" is correct either, sounds like a superfluous bloat function. Does it return a volatile type? Is it inlined or not? If it's inlined but not returning volatile, then it is bugged.

Comment: And finally, these ST MEMS parts have all manner of picky timing considerations on SPI. As always, SPI is poorly standardized. Always suspect clock skew because of wrong CPOL/CPHA, wrong delays and similar crap.